# Scanf changes wrong array when it is in do-while loop

Tags: c, arrays, while-loop, buffer, scanf

I need suggestions with this code.

This is code in which the program checks if the number is in range between 1 and 20. Problem occurs in these few lines because when I enter in while loop, `scanf()` changes numbers in 2 arrays, not only in one.

One is `numberToGuess` array and second is array in which numbers are "randomly" generated (I had used `srand(time(NULL))`). Function for random generator is only called once, before this code.

I guess it is because when while loop occurs he takes last address from buffer, but I am not sure how to fix it.

```
while(numberToGuess[i]<1 || numberToGuess[i]>20) {

    printf("Try again:\n");
    for(i=0;i<4;i++) {
        scanf(" %d", &numberToGuess[i]);
    }
}
```

EDIT: I had found solution , and it was unrelated to posted code. Problem occurred on part where I had declared arrays. Size of arrays was smaller than it should be(instead of 4 , it was 3). So when loop variable (i) was equal to 3 , scanf jumped to another memory location, which was location of second array and changed 1. On second array , when loop was equal 3 , he was out of array bounds and printed some "random value".

Comment: the space  in scanf is needed when you read a char " %c"

Comment: You're setting `i` in the `for` loop, but you're accessing it before you start the loop. That doesn't make sense. Can you show the whole code?

Comment: Did you allocate space for `numberToGuess`? I have a feeling it's an uninitialized pointer.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the inner loop.  Also, get rid of the space in the `scanf` pattern, since `%d` ignores them anyway.

```
while(numberToGuess[i]<1 || numberToGuess[i]>20){
    printf("Try again:\n");
    scanf("%d", &numberToGuess[i]);
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for suggestion , but code still doesn't work.

Comment: @tijetof What specifically does "doesn't work" mean?  A [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would help.

Comment: When I say doesn't work I mean program still changes numbers of second array.

Comment: @tijetof Then the problem is probably in the code you didn't show us.  MCVE, please.